# external hard drive still shows in disk utility after it was removed

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, external-disk

I unmounted and removed my backup disk called TimeMachine, but it still shows up in the disk utility app.

I tried running

```
$ diskutil unmount /dev/disk3s2
```

and

```
$ diskutil unmountdisk /dev/disk3
```

but it didn't help.

How can I make it stop showing in the disk utility?

￼￼[image: disk utility screen shot - external hard drive showing even though it was removed]

Comment: If you reboot the Mac without the external drive physically connected, does it still show in DisK Utility?

Comment: Try `disktuil eject disk3`

Comment: rebooting my laptop helped!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct command is given below.

```
diskutil eject disk3
```

You can also use the Finder and Disk Utility applications to eject a drive.

Occasionally, you may be using a drive that is not fully Mac compatible where the above command does not work. For example, I have an mp3 player that is not Mac compatible. When `diskutil eject` command is used, the player ejects only to remount a few seconds later. So, before removing the player from the USB port, I have to log out of my account to make sure all files are closed. In your case, you may have to shutdown the Mac before removing the drive.

Comment: unmount | umount [force] device
     Unmount a single volume.  Force will force-unmount the volume (less kind to any open
     files; see also umount (8)).

 unmountDisk | umountDisk [force] device
     Unmount an entire disk (all volumes).  Force will force-unmount the volumes (less kind
     to any open files; see also umount (8)).  You should specify a whole disk, but all
     volumes of the whole disk are attempted to be unmounted even if you specify a parti-
     tion.